# SurveyJS how do I not override existing afterRender on imagepicker in Survey Creator when adding properties and rendering using widget

Tags: surveyjs

I am trying to add a custom property to imagepicker for Survey Creator using a widget, and then do custom rendering in the preview and survey if the property is selected. The issue is this turns off the ability to add, move, remove and edit the images in the designer outside of the property grid.
Is it possible to have afterRender not override the question's existing afterRender?
If not, is there a way to duplicate the question's existing afterRender and where would I find it?

I know I can add the property outside of the widget, and then use survey.onAfterRenderQuestion in the viewer to do the rendering, but then a customer cannot preview the changes.